# Android Volley causes double POST sometimes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I have a problem with Volley POST request on slow network. Sometimes My POST request is executed twice or more resulting in multiple (2 or more) postings for 1 request.

I tried few solutions but no use,

Try 1:

```
request.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, 0, 1f)
```

Try 2:

```
request.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(0, -1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)
```

Try 3 : Increase the setRetryPolicy time.

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    30000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Try 4 : set the RetryPolicy to 0 retries and ensure that the timeout is bigger than the server timeout.

```
setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy("bigger than server timeout",
                                      0,
                                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Try 5 : Change the RetryPolicy.
I set the timeout value to 50000ms

```
request.setRetryPolicy(
                new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                        500000,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
                )
        );
```

Full source code :
https://androidkeynotes.blogspot.com/2020/02/volley.html

How to avoid duplicate POST using volley lib?

Comment: are you positive that you don't have two separate instances of something that invokes volley running ?

Comment: what is the outcome of each request ?

Comment: Try doing this.....  request.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried above solution but does not work

Comment: This issue happens randomly (BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request)

Answer (score 0):

Volly has mechanism to call post API 3 time if the response is not retrieve in define time. we can be change the time duration so it will get response in slower connection.